# how can I multiply strings in C like I do in python?

Tags: c, string

in python you can easily type:

```
str = "hi"
print(str * 10)
```

and the output would be hi printed 10 times. I'm currently learning how to code in C and I have to do this. Can someone teach me how I can do this kind of thing in C? Thanks in advance

Comment: Use a loop is the usual way in C.

Comment: @vbhargav875 How is `strcmp` relevant to repeating a string?

Comment: Sorry, meant 'strcat'

Answer (score 7):

## Use `for()` loop:

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  char* str = "hi";
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    printf("%s", str);
  }
}
```

And if you need to actually multiply the string (not just print n times) you can use the following `mulstr()`, just don't forget to test for NULL and to `free()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <error.h>

char* mulstr(char* str, size_t i) {
  size_t len = strlen(str);
  char* newstr = malloc(len * i + 1);
  if (newstr) {
    char* writer = newstr;
    for (; i; --i) {
      memcpy(writer, str, len);
      writer += len;
    }
    *writer = 0;
  } else {
    perror("malloc");
  }
  return newstr;
}

int main() {
  char* str = "hi";
  char* newstr = mulstr(str, 10);
  if (newstr) {
    printf("%s", newstr);
    free(newstr);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using **for-loop** is the best way to implement this.

You can just create a customized `print` function which will do the same thing as `python` does. I am just giving a prototype here.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print(char *string,int n)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
     printf("%s\n",string);   
    }
}

int main()
{
    char *str="Hi";
    print(str,2);
    return 0;
}
```

Here second argument in the function `n` will tell you how many times you want to print the `string`.

The output will look like

```
Hi
Hi
```

Comment: Note. that the newline in the format is not appropriate — the Python would print `hihihihihihihihihihi` as a single unit, no  newlines or spaces (unless the string to be repeated contains spaces or newlines, of course).  The `print` operator/function does add  a newline at the end, but assigning `result = "hi" * 10` does not include any  newline.

Comment: Modern C would use `for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) printf("%s", string);` with the variable definition in the `for` loop control line — unless you need to access the value after the loop, of course.